# C++: Conversion from T to unsigned T

Tags: c++, templates

We excessively use templates and we cannot always tell the signedness of a type at hand, so we need techniques to hide warnings that will be eventually optimized out. I have a simple `ASSERT(condition)` macro which throws something if the condition not evalutes to true.

The goal is to check the range of a `T` typed `count` value. We need it to be at least zero, at most the max of `size_t`.

```
template<typename SomeIntegral>
SomeIntegral ZERO()
{
    return SomeIntegral(0);
}

template<typename T>
class C
{
public:
  void f(T count)
  {
    std::vector<std::string> ret;
    ASSERT(count>=ZERO<T>()); // Check #1
    ASSERT(count<std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()); // Check #2
    ret.reserve(size_t(count)); // Needs check #1 and #2 to succeed.
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

The #1 check compiles without warning, but the #2 check says `comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions`, because in this particular case the count has a signed type. If I could say `ASSERT((unsigned T) count < std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())` or similar somehow... Converting to unsigned T is safe in this situation, because we know from check #1 that it is at least zero.

... or what other compiler agnostic approach can I use?

Comment: Why check agains `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` and not `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`?

Comment: because I will use the value as the parameter of `.reserve()` which requires `size_t` typed parameter. And that check you say is always true except when they are equal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use [**`std::make_signed`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_signed) or [**`std::make_unsigned`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned). Whichever fits the need.

---

Here is a custom implementation.

```
namespace internal {

    #define MK_MAKESIGNED(T,V)             \
    template<> struct make_signed<T> {     \
      public:                              \
        typedef V type;                    \
    };                                     


    template<typename T>
    struct make_signed {
        typedef T type;
    };

    MK_MAKESIGNED(unsigned int, signed int);
    MK_MAKESIGNED(unsigned char, signed char);
    // .... can convert anything to anything.

    #undef MK_MAKESIGNED

};


internal::make_signed<unsigned char>::type c;
```

Comment: I like it very much, but it is only from C++11. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned

Comment: There's always Boost's version http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/make_signed.html

Comment: @Notinlist Or if you use only the common integral types you can write your own. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Boost is compiler agnostic solution enough for me as it is not me who follows the compilers. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apply `static_cast<unsigned long>` to both left hand and right hand side expressions in your second assert:

```
ASSERT(static_cast<unsigned long>(count)
        < static_cast<unsigned long>(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()));
```

(I presume that your count is integer, not float - if I am wrong, go for a largest float type).

Comment: What if T is larger than `unsigned long`?

Comment: go for `long double`. This is the biggest standard c++ type as far as I know - see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/